# when i'm run project then show error (build.gradle.kts(:app)) file

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

this is error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V6gX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFrS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you add kotlin plugin in both :app and :module gradle.
add both your build.gradle.kts files to the question.